# Regular expression that matches string starting with "Mozilla/5.0 (iP" (not all alpha-numerical characters)

Tags: regex

Can someone help me with figuring out a regular expression for matching a string starting with `Mozilla/5.0 (iP` please? The end goal is to match a string starting with the above and ending with "30".

For the first bit, my initial reaction was to try quotation marks, i.e.:

`^"Mozilla/5.0 (iP"`

but apparently that is syntactically incorrect. So I tried escape characters, as below:

`^Mozilla\/5\.0 \(iP`

But also invalid syntax apparently. Any ideas?

My approach for the final reg-ex (including the end-matching bit) is, assuming the escaped version for the "string starting with" bit was correct (does this seem loosely correct?):

`^Mozilla\/5\.0 \(iP.*30$`

Thanks!

Sam

Comment: `^Mozilla\/5\.0 \(iP.*30$` should be fine, what is your regex flavor/tool?

Comment: @anubhava So I don't need to escape the space and am correct to escape the open round bracket? It's for a config file on Ubuntu

Comment: Yes that's right but still it is unclear what regex engine is this

Comment: @anubhava so am I - doesn't seem to be described anywhere. Please give the above as an answer and I will accept

Comment: As your own attempt is a fairly good regex, I would rather not add the same as answer. +1 for your attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be the last regex I posted: `^Mozilla\/5\.0 \(iP.*30$`. The tool I was using was adding null characters as I typed, but once that was fixed the above worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this for the PCRE flavour

`Mozilla\/5.0 \(iP ([\d]{0,3}[\.]{1}){3}30\)`

This matches

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iP 127.0.0.30)
Mozilla/5.0 (iP 174.66.34.30)
```

**Warning!** It will also match invalid IP ranges, such as:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iP 256.256.256.30) 
Mozilla/5.0 (iP 567.556.856.30)
```

However, if you were to be doing this, you could make sure they were in the valid range yourself.

It will not match anything that doesn't end with 30.

[See here](https://regex101.com/r/vY0kM3/1) to test it out for yourself.

Comment: thanks Kyle! Luckily it isn't an IP I'm trying to match, but with that tweak it works also.